# Angular UI Typeahead - Trigger typeahead-on-select when ng-model is updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-typeahead

I have a directive and I am using angular ui typeahead. The `myModel` has 2 way binding. I will be updating the `myModel` value in the controller and I want to trigger `typeahead-on-select` whenever the myModel value changes.

`<input type="text" ng-model="myModel" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" uib-typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control" typeahead-on-select="myFunc()">`

So when `myModel` value is updated I need to run `myFunc()`. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-change="myFunc()" directive inside your input.

It will run myFunc whenever your myModel value is changed